# JQuery 1.4.4 and Datatable 1.7 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, datatable

I needed some help with datatables. I might be missing something here:-

Below is my HTML

```
<div id="cfcPhoneDirectory">
<table id="dynamicPhoneDirectory">
    <thead>
       <tr><th>Phone Book</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Number</th></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And the Script

```
    var rawxmlData = "<PhoneBooks><PhoneBook><name>PhoneBook1</name><type>GLOBAL</type><Contacts><Contact><LNAME>Elis</LNAME><FNAME>Jason</FNAME><Number>1234567890</Number></Contact><Contact><LNAME>Randell</LNAME><FNAME>Mark</FNAME><Number>7895896710</Number></Contact><Contact><LNAME>Flower</LNAME><FNAME>Andy</FNAME><Number>8796024589</Number></Contact></Contacts></PhoneBook><PhoneBook><name>PhoneBook2</name><type>TEAM</type><Contacts><Contact><LNAME>Cullinan</LNAME><FNAME>David</FNAME><Number>6027051573</Number></Contact><Contact><LNAME>Webber</LNAME><FNAME>Mark</FNAME><Number>4842051298</Number></Contact><Contact><LNAME>Mitchell</LNAME><FNAME>Randy</FNAME><Number>7012841562</Number></Contact></Contacts></PhoneBook></PhoneBooks>";

    var t = $('#dynamicPhoneDirectory').DataTable();


    var xmlData = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson(rawxmlData));

    ($(xmlData)).find("PhoneBook").each(function () 
    {
       var phoneBookType = $(this).find("type").text()
       $(this).find("Contact").each(function () {     t.row.add([phoneBookType,     $(this).find("LNAME").text(),                     $(this).find("FNAME").text(), $(this).find("Number").text()]).draw();
       });
    });
    // Changes XML to JSON
    function xmlToJson(xml) {

        // Create the return object
        var obj = {};

        if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
            // do attributes
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
            obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }

        // do children
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
                } else {
                    if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                        var old = obj[nodeName];
                        obj[nodeName] = [];
                        obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    };
```

I am using Jquery version of 1.4.4 and datatable version of 1.7.5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Hash

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trapped on such old versions of those libraries?

Comment: We are using Cisco finesse api which supports Jquery 1.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up debugging the XML parsing - too cryptic. There is no need for porting the XML to JSON at all. So made this up instead :

```js
var table = $('#dynamicPhoneDirectory').dataTable();

var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(rawxmlData,"text/xml"),
    phoneBook = xmlDoc.querySelector('PhoneBooks'),
    phoneBooks = phoneBook.querySelectorAll('PhoneBook');

for (var i=0;i<phoneBooks.length;i++) {
    var firstname, lastname, number, contacts,
        phoneBookName = phoneBooks[i].querySelector('name').textContent,
        phoneBookContacts = phoneBooks[i].querySelector('Contacts'),
        contacts = phoneBookContacts.querySelectorAll('Contact');
    for (var c=0;c<contacts.length;c++) {
        lastName = contacts[c].querySelector('LNAME').textContent;
        firstName = contacts[c].querySelector('FNAME').textContent;        
        number = contacts[c].querySelector('Number').textContent;        
        //add the contact to dataTables
        table.fnAddData([phoneBookName, lastName, firstName, number]);
    }        
}
```

this works with datatables **1.7.5** -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nsmqg4n2/**
the used jQuery is 1.6.4, the lowest possible in jsFiddle, but that does not really inflict on the above code after all. jQuery dataTables 1.7.5 just need jQuery 1.3.x or better.

---

To retrieve data (for example when the table is clicked) use the API method [**`fnGetData()`**](https://datatables.net/api#fnGetData), example (jQuery 1.6.4, dataTables 1.7.5) :

```js
$("#dynamicPhoneDirectory").delegate('tbody tr', 'click', function() { 
    var data = table.fnGetData(this);
    alert('Number to dial : '+data[3]);
});
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bu87ke7a/**

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help. Can you also help on getting the value of any column for the selected row?

Comment: I mean like getting value from 3rd row and 2nd column.

          $(document).delegate(  "#dynamicPhoneDirectory tbody", "click", 'tr', function() {
          var number = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
         $("#cfcNumberToDial").val( "");
         $("#cfcNumberToDial").val(number);
         //$("#cfcNumberToDial").focus();
         alert( 'You clicked on '+ number);
         } );

Comment: @user3299242 - and you are now using dataTables 1.10.7? (or NOT below 1.10)

Comment: I am using Datatable 1.7.5, with jquery 1.4.4

Comment: Hi David, my datatable is a created dynamically in a function on a button click. I did set bRetrieve: true. 
but on trying to retrieve the data, I am getting the below error oSettings.aoData[iRow] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my code to use JQuery 1.9.1 and Datatable1.10.7 resolved the issue.